# Box Like Icons In Application List Won't Go Away

Tags: 12.10

Picture on http://tempquestionimageserver.weebly.com/ sorry, I put a picture on this post and it said new members couldn't do that.

These box like icons won't go away. They won't move to the trash. When you right click on an application it expands with info, on the box icons it expands but no information. When you click on an application it closes the app list and opens the app, with the box things it doesn't close the app list and doesn't open anything.

As far as I can remember I don't think I've ever asked a question online about something that I couldn't figure out. I always found the answer somewhere on the internet, but this time I just couldn't find the answer. Please help me figure out how to get these off my app list.

Comment: try to remove your software-center cache folder: rm /home/$USER/.cache/software-center -R in a terminal window

Comment: Sorry, it didn't work even after reboot. Thanks anyway. At least it's not doing any harm. I guess I'll just leave it there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the icons are because of updates and such. I decided not to touch them. I found that out by looking here: usr/share/applications.